# Images with grayscale filter overlapping navbar when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this and I'm having an issue with images overlapping navbar when scrolling.
It only happens when I apply a -webkitfilter grayscale on hover.
If I delete it from the style sheet everything goes back to normal.

Here it is:

```
.images {
color: darkgray;
font-size: 0.9rem;
filter: gray; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
```

}

```
.images:hover {
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
```

}

The url is this: http://josefinaechenique.esy.es/musica.html

[overlapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByJma.png)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `z-index: 9999;` to your `#fixedbar` everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Html when renders overlaps as it finds new elements.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#a {
  background: red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#b {
  background: blue;
  left: 60px;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You can overwrite this behaviour by using the z-index property.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#a {
  background: red;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
#b {
  background: blue;
  left: 60px;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

You need to add `z-index: 999` or preferably a larger number inside your `#fixedbar` styling.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's going on without having the HTML code, a work around which might work is adding a z-index after having the filter applied this will helped out.

```
.images {
color: darkgray;
font-size: 0.9rem;
filter: gray; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
z-index: -1;
}
```

Add it after the filter on hover as well if it's causing an issue.

```
.images:hover {
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
z-index: -1;
}
```

This should this your issue. Having Web-Dev!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `z-index`. Give the "z-index:value" on nav div in css. problem will be solved.
And it will solve not only grayscale hover problem it's solves other div's over lapping with nav bar

NOTE: In below image look at Style and observe `z-index`.

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]